# How to map structured data to schemaRDD in Spark?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've asked this question differently before but there are some changes so I thought asking it again as a new question.
I have a structured data which only part of it is in json format but I need to map the entire data to an schemaRDD. The data looks like this:

> 03052015 04:13:20
>   {"recordType":"NEW","data":{"keycol":"val1","col2":"val2","col3":"val3"}

Each line starts with date followed by time and a json formatted text.
I need to map not only the text in json but also the date and time into the same structure.

I tried it in Python but obviously it doesn't work because Row does not take an RDD (jsonRDD in this case).

```
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    orderFile  = sc.textFile(myfile)
    orderLine  = orderFile.map(lambda line: line.split(" ", 2))
    anotherOrderLine = orderLine.map(lambda p: Row(date=p[0], time=p[1], content=sqlContext.jsonRDD(p[3])))
    schemaOrder = sqlContext.inferSchema(anotherOrderLine)
    schemaOrder.printSchema()
    for x in schemaOrder.collect():
        print x
```

The goal is to be able to run a query like this against the schemaRDD:

```
select date, time, data.keycol, data.val1, data.val2, data.val3 from myOrder
```

How can I map the entire line to a schemaRDD?

Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option would be to add this field to JSON and use jsonRDD

My data:

```
03052015 04:13:20 {"recordType":"NEW","data":{"keycol":"val1","col1":"val5","col2":"val3"}}
03062015 04:13:20 {"recordType":"NEW1","data":{"keycol":"val2","col1":"val6","col2":"val3"}}
03072015 04:13:20 {"recordType":"NEW2","data":{"keycol":"val3","col1":"val7","col2":"val3"}}
03082015 04:13:20 {"recordType":"NEW3","data":{"keycol":"val4","col1":"val8","col2":"val3"}}
```

Code:

```
import json

def transform(data):
    ts  = data[:18].strip()
    jss = data[18:].strip()
    jsj = json.loads(jss)
    jsj['ts'] = ts
    return json.dumps(jsj)

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
rdd = sc.textFile('/sparkdemo/sample.data')
tbl = sqlContext.jsonRDD(rdd.map(transform))
tbl.registerTempTable("myOrder")

sqlContext.sql("select ts, recordType, data.keycol, data.col1, data.col2 data from myOrder").collect()
```

Result:

```
[Row(ts=u'03052015 04:13:20', recordType=u'NEW', keycol=u'val1', col1=u'val5', data=u'val3'), Row(ts=u'03062015 04:13:20', recordType=u'NEW1', keycol=u'val2', col1=u'val6', data=u'val3'), Row(ts=u'03072015 04:13:20', recordType=u'NEW2', keycol=u'val3', col1=u'val7', data=u'val3'), Row(ts=u'03082015 04:13:20', recordType=u'NEW3', keycol=u'val4', col1=u'val8', data=u'val3')]
```

In your code there is a problem that you are calling jsonRDD for each of the rows, this is not correct - it accepts an RDD and returns SchemaRDD.

Answer (score 0):

The sqlContext.jsonRDD creates a schema rdd from an RDD containing strings where each string contains a JSON representation. This code sample is from the SparkSQL documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html):

```
val anotherPeopleRDD = sc.parallelize("""{"name":"Yin","address":{"city":"Columbus","state":"Ohio"}}""" :: Nil)
val anotherPeople = sqlContext.jsonRDD(anotherPeopleRDD)
```

One of the cool things about jsonRDD is the fact that you can provide and additional parameter stating the JSONs schema, which should improve performance your performance. This can be don by creating an schemaRDD (just load a sample document) and then call the schemaRDD.schema method to get the schema.